# How to find out if a transaction is finalized on Solana

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

How do you get the current status of a transaction on Solana with the Solana Javascript API (@solana/web3.js)?

https://solscan.io/tx/4fwgX16WDwYj5hZ2t5xEHz6UUnuaTovJpMeoWWEBvuA7z1baf1qX1BW2EGZVR9ChSyJZ8akeLX6EDTadFcEcSTdy

This is what I've tried, but it only seems to work for recent transactions.

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl } = require("@solana/web3.js");

(async () => {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
    const status = await connection.getSignatureStatus("4fwgX16WDwYj5hZ2t5xEHz6UUnuaTovJpMeoWWEBvuA7z1baf1qX1BW2EGZVR9ChSyJZ8akeLX6EDTadFcEcSTdy");
    console.log(status);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `searchTransactionHistory: true` to the `SignatureStatusConfig`

```
const getConfirmation = async (connection: Connection, tx: string) => {
  const result = await connection.getSignatureStatus(tx, {
    searchTransactionHistory: true,
  });
  return result.value?.confirmationStatus;
};
```

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturestatuses

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `confirmTransaction` function:

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl } = require("@solana/web3.js");

(async () => {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
    const result = await connection.confirmTransaction({
        signature: "4fwgX16WDwYj5hZ2t5xEHz6UUnuaTovJpMeoWWEBvuA7z1baf1qX1BW2EGZVR9ChSyJZ8akeLX6EDTadFcEcSTdy"
    },
    'finalized');
    console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting your connection's commitment level to "finalized"

```
new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'finalized');
```